# luajit ffi - How to program a pointer to a c function in ffi/luajit

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

Quite the neophyte when it comes to ffi, looking for help in getting this c/c++ declaration coded in lua via ffi.

The way I read the code, I have a function that has a pointer to a function as one of the passed parameters. I could be totally wrong, I did say I was a neophyte!

This is the typedef:

```
ffi.cdef[[typedef void (* XPLMReceiveMonitorBoundsGlobal_f)(
                               int                  inMonitorIndex,    
                               int                  inLeftBx,    
                               int                  inTopBx,    
                               int                  inRightBx,    
                               int                  inBottomBx,    
                               void *               inRefcon);]]
```

and this is the function definition:

```
ffi.cdef("void XPLMGetAllMonitorBoundsGlobal(XPLMReceiveMonitorBoundsGlobal_f inMonitorBoundsCallback, void * inRefcon)")
```

I have tried to guess how to code this in lua for about 4 hours using whatever my imagination could muster, such as:

```
XPLM.XPLMGetAllMonitorBoundsOS(XPLMReceiveMonitorBoundsOS_f(monindex, leftpx, toppx, rightpx, bottompx, nil), nil)

XPLM.XPLMGetAllMonitorBoundsOS(), nil)
```

Nothing I have thought of works, and Google searches and lots of reading have not brought me any closer to the answer.

The coding is for a lua app within the XPlane flight simulator, the closest thing to an error I get is:

```
"attempt to call global 'XPLMReceiveMonitorBoundsOS_f' (a nil value)"
```

Maybe I have to define something via an ffi.new(), ffi.cast(), etc, etc, whatever it is I certainly haven't come up with the answer.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Ian

Comment: `XPLMReceiveMonitorBoundsOS_f` is not a function, it's a placeholder for callback function.  You should write callback function in C, then `ffi.cast` its pointer to  corresponding ctype and pass it as first argument to `XPLMGetAllMonitorBoundsOS`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, will give it a try.